# Getting error in his simple java code

Tags: java

I am a starter in java and getting error on compiling this java code whats the error please help me!

```
class sum { 
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
          int x,y,z; 
          sum = x + y + z; 
          System.out.println ("Sum is "    + sum); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at the error, and research the possible causes of it. Also you should post the error aswell

Comment: Where do you define `sum`, I don't see no `int sum;` or `int sum = x + y + z;` somewhere. You should always initialize local variables with values i.e. `x`, `y` and `z` must be initialized. Otherwise you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: class attendence
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
int sal,timing;
float ondeday,deduction;
sal=10000;
timing=12;
oneday= sal/30;
if (timing<=10)
{
deduction = oneday*0.10;
System.out.println("YOur todays salary deduction is" + deduction);
}
else if (timing>12)
{
deduction = oneday*0.20;
System.out.println("YOur todays salary deduction is" + deduction);
}
else
{
deduction = oneday/2;
System.out.println("YOur todays salary deduction is" + deduction);
}
}
}

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize yours varible, for example:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
```

And you must add declaretion to your `sum` variable:

```
int sum = x + y + z;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your x, y, z variables are not initialized.  They need to have some value before they are used.

Comment: And sum doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You never put values into these variables:

```
int x,y,z;
```

What you need to do is:

```
int x = 7, y = 2, z = -9;
```

Or whichever values  you desire.

Also, you never declared the variable `sum`. You can do so as the following:

```
int sum = x + y + z;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `int` variables some values before using them. They currently don't hold any value and hence you cannot add them up. Plus, the `sum` variable is not declared either.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
class sum { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int x,y,z; 
        sum = x + y + z; 
        System.out.println ("Sum is "    + sum); 
    } 
}
```

to

```
class GetTheSum { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int x = 1, y = 2,z = 3; 
        int sum = x + y + z; 
        System.out.println ("Sum is "    + sum); 
    } 
}
```

The problems with your original code:

```
class sum {
```

You are creating `sum` as a *class*. A class is not an int, and therefore cannot hold the result of `x + y + z`. Also, the *variable* `sum` inside the *class* `sum` is does not make sense--they are completely different things that happen to have the same name.

```
        int x,y,z;
```

This creates three ints each equal to `0` which is likely not what you want. They need to be assigned explicit values.

```
        sum = x + y + z;
```

Again, `sum` is never initialized, and therefore cannot hold any values yet--the class `sum` is a completely different entity.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your variables `x y z`. You also have to declare the type of your variable `sum`. In case you just want to get sum of three specific numbers you can try doing it like this:

```
public class sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;
        int z = 3;

        int sum = x + y + z;

        System.out.println("Sum of your numbers is " + sum);
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to input different numbers through console every time you start a program you can try to do it by importing java utility `Scanner`. For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x, y, z;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  //create new Scanner object named 'sc'

        System.out.println("Insert value for variable 'x': ");
        x = sc.nextInt();  //value of x becomes the next integer read from Scanner

        System.out.println("Insert value for variable 'y': ");
        y = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Insert value for variable 'y': ");
        z = sc.nextInt();

        int sum = x + y + z;

        System.out.println("\nSum of your numbers is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Hopefully it will help you or anyone else with the similar problem.